# Change details in SQL scripts from C#

Tags: c#, sql

Here are the details: I am testing changes to over 400 SQL scripts in a test environment. When the scripts were written they were written to work in the production environment. In our test environment, all database names are appended by "_backup". I need to use c# to go into each SQL query and change the database name from "dbName" to "dbName_backup".

Comment: why not use a nice text editor? like notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do what you are asking.
If you want, you could:

1. Get a list of all the DB names.
2. Write a program to find each instance of a database name.
3. Check that the found instance is actually a database name and not a column name, table name, or something else.
4. Append the "_backup" text to each confirmed instance of a database name.

Personally I would probably add all the script files to a project in Visual Studios, then use Replace in Files (Ctrl+Shift+H) to find each instance of each database name, check if it is indeed a database name, and do the replace.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do any of these needed changes, you should go into your application and create a static function like this:

```
private static const bool UsingProduction = false; // or true

public static string GetDatabaseName(string table)
{
    return UsingProduction ? table : table + "_backup";
}
```

This way, when you push your application to production, simply change the value to `true`.

And modify your scripts to be something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + GetDatabaseName("Customer");
```

On production, this will evaluate to `SELECT * FROM Customer`, and on your development, it will evaluate to `SELECT * FROM Customer_backup`

Also, if this is a web application, stick the `UsingProduction` value in your `web.config` file!